# Pretty Radio Buttons using rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, simple-form, form-for

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap 3, the one that produces the pretty blue buttons. I would like to, using either rails form_for or simple_form, produce a radio_button group that looks the same as the following html one does:

```
    <div class= "form-group">
        <div class= "btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="ptype", id="freelancer">
                Freelancer
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name= "ptype" id="agency">
                Agency
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That is, I would like the radio button group to look like the bottom option in the image below, rather than the top.

[image: buttons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Freelancer
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Agency
  </label>
</div>
```

You will need the specific javascript for this to work.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Comment: Could you be more specific? I am fairly new to this and have little to no experience in javascript/jQuery

Comment: Also I'm still wondering how you would write this into a rails form_for function

Answer (score 0):

that's how I fixed it, the rails way:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <%= radio_button_tag :flight_id, flight.id %>select
  </label>
</div>
```